# How to embed matplotlib or pyplot into Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, grid

I'm just a beginner in Python 3. After referring some tutorials and examples I managed to plot graphs. I built a GUI for my project and now want to display a graph on GUI.

I found these examples in internet

[user_interfaces example code: embedding_in_tk.py](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk.html)

But I want to embed my figure into Python 3 and also I'm using grid here not pack.
Can somebody please give me a solution? or a place to look?

Thank you in advance =)

--ps--

Let's say I want to embed the figure obtained in this

```
from pylab import *

# make a square figure and axes
figure(1, figsize=(6,6))
ax = axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8])

# The slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise.
labels = 'Frogs', 'Hogs', 'Dogs', 'Logs'
fracs = [15, 30, 45, 10]
explode=(0, 0.05, 0, 0)

pie(fracs, explode=explode, labels=labels,
                autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90)
                # The default startangle is 0, which would start
                # the Frogs slice on the x-axis.  With startangle=90,
                # everything is rotated counter-clockwise by 90 degrees,
                # so the plotting starts on the positive y-axis.

title('Raining Hogs and Dogs', bbox={'facecolor':'0.8', 'pad':5})  
show()
```

to below program

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk   

def calculate(*args):
    try:
        value = float(feet.get())
        meters.set((0.3048 * value * 10000.0 + 0.5)/10000.0)
    except ValueError:
        pass

root = Tk()
root.title("Feet to Meters")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="3 3 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

feet = StringVar()
meters = StringVar()

feet_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=7, textvariable=feet)
feet_entry.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=(W, E))

ttk.Label(mainframe, textvariable=meters).grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=(W, E))
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Calculate", command=calculate).grid(column=3, row=3, sticky=W)

ttk.Label(mainframe, text="feet").grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="is equivalent to").grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=E)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="meters").grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=W)

for child in mainframe.winfo_children(): child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=5)    


feet_entry.focus()
root.bind('<Return>', calculate)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you mean *"into Python 3"*? Are you still using Tkinter?

Comment: yeah.. I used Tkinter to make the GUI

Comment: So what is the problem you've had adapting that to your code? Could you give a [mcve]?

Comment: @jonrsharpe - I edited my question.. hope that will give you an idea about my problem.. 
by the way why did you asked "Are you still using Tkinter?"
is there another way??

Comment: There are other GUI toolkits, yes, although Tkinter is the only one bundled with Python. Your question still doesn't explain the *problem* with your current code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know how to obtain a figure.. But my problem is that I don't know how to obtain and display a figure/graph in a GUI :( 

e.g. when you click a button, then a graph should be displayed on GUI

I mean something like this :-
https://nf.nci.org.au/facilities/software/Matlab/techdoc/creating_guis/qs_actfi.gif

In the above code I shared, what I want to do is embed the pie graph (as a image) in the below part in GUI.. I'm sorry if that confused you, all I want to know is how to embed a figure inside the grid in  python3 tkinter